# Working with Files, loop not stopping where i want to

Tags: c#, loops

I'm currently working on a C# program that requires me to write a program that receives information about several students and then stores the entered data into two files: a text file and a binary file.  Write your program such that when you run it, the program asks the user for the number of students that is intended to be entered and then the program asks the data (Student Name, Student Height, Student Weight) about that any number of students to be entered, the data is stored in to two files: one text file and one binary file. My issue right now is that whenever I run the loop, it does not stop where I want it to, which is the amount that the user inputs in the beginning. If you have any help please feel free to comment. 
Thanks.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

namespace BinaryAssignment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter outputFile;
            FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream("outFile.bin", FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter myOutputFile = new BinaryWriter(fsOutput);
            outputFile = new StreamWriter("ex1.txt");
            outputFile = new StreamWriter("ex1.bin");
            double studentAmount ;
            string studentName;
            int studentHeight;
            double studentWeight;

            Write("Data of how many students do you want to enter? ");
            studentAmount = double.Parse(ReadLine());

            double x = 0;
            do
            {
                Write("Enter the name of the student: ");
                studentName = ReadLine();
                myOutputFile.Write(studentName);
                outputFile.WriteLine(studentName);

                Write("Enter the height of the student in centimeters: ");
                studentHeight = int.Parse(ReadLine());
                outputFile.WriteLine(studentHeight);
                myOutputFile.Write(studentHeight);

                Write("Enter the weight of the student in kilograms: ");
                studentWeight = double.Parse(ReadLine());
                outputFile.WriteLine(studentWeight);
                myOutputFile.Write(studentWeight);

            } while ((x = studentAmount) >= 0);

            outputFile.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();





        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin. You have to double check your condition in the while. You wrote literally "assign studentAmount to x more or equal to zero". You can come up with solution here on your own, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

you loop stops when this is no longer true

```
while ((x = studentAmount) >= 0);
```

You never change studentAmount, so the loop will run forever

you need a `studentAmount--` somewhere

Simpler and clearer would be

```
for(int i = 0; i < studentAmount; i++)
{
   .....
}
```

instead of your do / while loop

Comment: Or  `++x` if that was OP's intent with that variable. I 100% agree that a `for` loop makes a lot more sense here. The intent of the loop is stated right at the top and there is incremented automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO Kevin. Looks like you are just learning the Programming. As Pm100 already mentioned; you are running into loop called Infinite Loop.
For your solution, just replace these lines.

```
    double x = 0;
        do
        {
            .....
            x=x+1;  //Add this line
        } while (x < studentAmount);  //Change the condition like this
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is a big help!

Answer (score 0):

Kevin - The code you posted won't run as is - you forgot the 'Console.' before the read/write. You should also validate the input - but your specific issue was that you weren't terminating the loop. Please see comments in the code below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream("outFile.bin", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter myOutputFile = new BinaryWriter(fsOutput);
        outputFile = new StreamWriter("ex1.txt");
        outputFile = new StreamWriter("ex1.bin");
        int studentAmount;      // This should be an int not double
        string studentName;
        int studentHeight;
        double studentWeight;

        Console.Write("Data of how many students do you want to enter? ");

        // You should validate the input using the appropriate TryParse
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!int.TryParse(input, out studentAmount))
        {
            // You need to append 'Console.' to the beginning of the read/write operations
            Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number for  student amounnt - ending...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        // double x = 0;    // You don't need this variable
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the name of the student: ");
            studentName = Console.ReadLine();
            myOutputFile.Write(studentName);
            outputFile.WriteLine(studentName);

            Console.Write("Enter the height of the student in centimeters: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!int.TryParse(input, out studentHeight))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number for  height - ending...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return; 
            }
            outputFile.WriteLine(studentHeight);
            myOutputFile.Write(studentHeight);
            Console.Write("Enter the weight of the student in kilograms: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!double.TryParse(input, out studentWeight))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number for weight - ending...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            outputFile.WriteLine(studentWeight);
            myOutputFile.Write(studentWeight);

            // You need to decrement your counter so you don't loop forever
        } while (--studentAmount > 0);

        outputFile.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```